# convert date into numbers

Tags: r, ubuntu

I have a bunch of dates:

```
dates
 [1] "24/06/2010" NA           NA           NA           "11/05/2005" NA           "24/02/2006"
 [8] NA           NA           NA           "27/10/2008" "09/05/2009" NA           NA          
[15] "14/12/2008" "14/12/2008" NA           "07/04/2009" NA
```

And wanna make a new vector where the dates are transformed into numbers and the NA transformed into -1 values. I know that in Excel dates are converted into numbers according to a standard procedure, here I don't know.

So for example if we fix as starting date 01/01/2008 as number 0 and count from there

24/06/2010 would be 905 days from the starting date.

Comment: Please add the expected output for the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach:

```
# the reference date
starting_date <- as.Date("2008-01-01") 
# transform the character vector to a date vector and subtract the reference date
res <- as.Date(dates, "%d/%m/%Y") - starting_date
# replace NAs with -1
res[is.na(res)] <- -1
```

The result:

```
# Time differences in days
#  [1]  905   -1   -1   -1 -965   -1 -676   -1   -1   -1  300  494   -1   -1  348
# [16]  348   -1  462   -1
```

Comment: not being an R expert myself, would you care to comment on which of these two answers has better performance? is a single ifelse() better than the subsetting you do in yours?

Comment: @imsoconfused The function `ifelse` is relatively slow. Usually, simple replacement is faster.

Answer (score 0):

[Updated] Does this fit your question?

```
ifelse(is.na(dates),-1,as.Date(strptime(dates,'%d/%m/%Y'))-as.Date("2008-01-01"))
```

Comment: almost, I think he then wants the POSIX time - designated start time as an integer of days. I think

Comment: In this case just leave the `as.numeric` away

Comment: POSIX time is in seconds, and I just want days, also i need to know the starting date.

Comment: mm no, I mean you just need to add in a `- starting_date`

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I updated my solution in the way as the solution of Sven Hohenstein

Comment: Your method works too, but Hohenstein is more self explaining I think. Matter of taste maybe. Thx for the help!